# 301 redirects are adding ?page=

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've set up some 301 redirects in my .htaccess file... for files that don't exist. They are indeed redirecting but with an added query. For example:

Using one of my redirects on my htaccess file below:
if I type in example.com/about-example.php it should redirect me to example.com/about-example.html and it kind of is but it takes me to example.com/about-example.html?page=about-example.php with this added ?page=(redirect) and moz is seeing that redirected page with a query at the end as a duplicate to the original page.

Here is what my htaccess looks like... (changing a lot to example/xyz)

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Remove "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect any requests for html files to index
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html index.php?page=$1 [L]

# Rewrite any request for subdirectories to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

## SITE REFERRER BANNING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*example\.net/ [NC,OR]




## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# 6 month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gs|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1576800, public"
</filesMatch>

# 1 month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML components (HTCs)
ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

  # HTML
ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media
ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web feeds
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

  # Web fonts
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>


Redirect 301 /about-example.php http://example.com/about-example.html
Redirect 301 /vacation-faq.php http://example.com/faqs.html
Redirect 301 /3d-tour.html http://example.com/plans.html
Redirect 301 /images/cool/04.jpg http://example.com/gallery.html
```

Am I missing a command, or are the redirects in the wrong place? I have tried rewrite rules, redirectmatch... and a bunch of other things with either the same result or 500 internal errors.. (edit) I have also messed with the placement of the redirects to no avail..

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but you have a specific rewrite to do this `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: I'll edit my main comment to explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your rule and add a `?` at the end. Try these rules instead.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
#if request is a real file or dir do nothing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#else do these redirects
RewriteRule ^about-example\.php http://example.com/about-example.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^vacation-faq\.php http://example.com/faqs.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^3d-tour\.html http://example.com/plans.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^images/cool/04\.jpg http://example.com/gallery.html? [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how this answer works for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. So I tested it with one, and it does redirect to a page, but now it has a ? at the end of the URL. Is that supposed to happen? Also, what does the ? actually do?

Comment: @dhath here try using Rewrite instead. I modified the 4 rules. The `?` tells it to drop any query string and don't append it if it's in the request.

Comment: I used rewrite and it just went to the 404 page. The RedirectMatch 301 works, just wondering if the "?" at the end of the page counts as a different page resulting in duplicate content? `RewriteRule ^contact\.php http://example.com/contact-example.html? [R=301,L]` is what I put.

Comment: I meant ? at the end of the URL not page.

Comment: are the pages you redirect to real pages?

Comment: yes they're pages that exist. I'm redirecting pages that don't exist to pages that actually do exist.

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact.php http://toscanaofdesertridge.com/contact-toscana.html?` is the actual code.. so when I type in toscanaofdesertridge.com/contact.php it goes to toscanaofdesertridge.com/contact-toscana.html? but why doesn't it just go to /contact-toscana.html with no ?

Comment: Ok I updated the rules so if use the rewriterule example it will handle real files etc but it shouldn't be getting a 404. I'm not really sure if having the `?` after words still counts as dupes.

Comment: In order to remove the ? also you need to use the rewrite version. It will leave it on the end with RedirectMatch

Comment: Alright so I tested the new code you put up, and it still went to a 404. Could it be an existing command in my .htaccess file that's causing this to happen?? I might just settle with redirectmatch, if it is not counted as a dupe which i'll check with a crawler. Do my other lines in my .htaccess file look okay (in main comment)?

Comment: I used rewrite rule closer to the top of my file, under rewrite engine on and it is now working correctly.. `RewriteRule ^contact\.php http://toscanaofdesertridge.com/contact-toscana.html? [R=301,L]` thanks again Jack.